# access to property found with isMemberOfClass

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

How can I get access to a property of a ViewController when I have created an object of it like this:

```
for (UIViewController* vc in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
    {
            if ([vc isMemberOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"myViewController")])
            {
                // change property value on viewcontroller vc, for instance: vc.myText = @"hello" ??
            }
        }
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast to let the compiler know the data type (or cheat and set it by an indirect method):

```
myViewController *mvc = (myViewController *)vc;
mvc.myText = @"hello";
```

Note also that class names should start with a capital first letter.

Answer (score 0):

Just use simply like this:
`(myViewController *)vc.myText = @"hello"`

`myText` needs to be public variable also.